# Bitmap size exceeds VM budget memory error

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap

I am setting a bitmap as my background which works fine with no errors. However when I press the back button and go to the activity with the background again I get the above out of memory error. Is there something I need to clear when the activity loses focus?

Code for setting bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    map = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mapFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

I then use createScaledBitmap() to set the image.

This out of memory issue only occurs when I leave the activity and go back onto it. The first time it works fine, so I am guessing I am creating multiple bitmap images in memory but can't see where?

Here is the decodeFile() method if there is something in there:

```
try {
                // decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
                // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
                int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;

                int scale = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                            || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp /= 2;
                    height_tmp /= 2;
                    scale++;
                }

                // decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android [training](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) about bitmap memory management.

Regarding your question, try to call `Bitmap.recycle()` when you are done with the bitmap, for instance in the `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: Hi this is what I was thinking. Is onDestory() called though when I just use the back button and then go back on the activity? I assumed that it would just be paused?

Comment: Got it homie, recycled on onStop()

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html),

> Android devices can have as little as 16MB of memory available to a single application.

Basically your images are being loaded but not being released from the app hence leaving low space hence why the error occurs. I was facing this error a little while back until I stumbled upon a tutorial on how to solve it. I suggest following the steps on it. Here is the [tutorial](http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/solution-for-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/)